# sokhotski-Plemelj formula proof using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

So I am asked to prove the  Sokhotski-Plemelj formula:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow0} \int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x+i\epsilon}dx=-i\pi f(0)+PV\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$
Using contour integrals, assuming $a\lt 0 \lt b$ ..I was told to deform the contour near $x=0$ and take the limit first.

This would then lead me to multiply the fraction by the complex conjugate to get:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow0} \int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x+i\epsilon}\frac{x-i\epsilon}{x-i\epsilon}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow0}\left[{ \int_a^b\frac{xf(x)}{x^2+\epsilon^2}dx-i\epsilon\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x^2+\epsilon^2}dx }\right]$$
I know the first term on the right had side becomes the principle value integral, but when I create a contour that "avoids" the residue at $x=0$ (because we take the limit) I don't really get the formula. Could someone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the origin by taking a small semicircle around it. You have two choices: Going above, or going below. The difference of the two results will be the integral around the whole circle. I trust you know the result of that. The crucial bit is to note that the integral around each semicircle is, to a very good approximation, equal to one half the integral around the entire semicircle. To see this, write up the integral explicitly, and note that $f(x)\approx f(0)$ on the circle.

Comment: Just noticed a typo: “around the entire semicircle” should of course be “around the entire *circle*”. To avoid gratuitously bumping this to the front page, I leave it as is.